# Capture images using usb Camera using C# desktop app

Tags: c#, camera, capture

I am developing an app in which i want to capture images from a usb camera, i have seen many examples on the internet in which you have to initialize video first and then capture images from in using a button configured to do so. the problem is i want to capture the images without initializing the video first so it has to done be anonymously and then save it in some folder and write its location in database
any idea how it can be done?

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
// Important: include the opencvsharp library in your code
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
namespace Sandbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Create class-level accesible variables
        VideoCapture capture;
        Mat frame;
        Bitmap image;
        private Thread camera;
        bool isCameraRunning = false;
        // Declare required methods
        private void CaptureCamera()
        {
            camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
            camera.Start();
        }
        private void CaptureCameraCallback()
        {
            frame = new Mat();
            capture = new VideoCapture(0);
            capture.Open(0);
            if (capture.IsOpened())
            {
                while (isCameraRunning)
                {
                    capture.Read(frame);
                    image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    }
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                }
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             
        }
        // When the user clicks on the start/stop button, start or release the camera and setup flags
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text.Equals("Start"))
            {
                CaptureCamera();
                button1.Text = "Stop";
                isCameraRunning = true;
            }
            else
            {
                capture.Release();
                button1.Text = "Start";
                isCameraRunning = false;
            }
        }
        // When the user clicks on take snapshot, the image that is displayed in the pictureBox will be saved in your computer
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCameraRunning)
            {
                // Take snapshot of the current image generate by OpenCV in the Picture Box
                Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
                // Save in some directory
                // in this example, we'll generate a random filename e.g 47059681-95ed-4e95-9b50-320092a3d652.png
                // snapshot.Save(@"C:\Users\sdkca\Desktop\mysnapshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                snapshot.Save(string.Format(@"C:\Users\sdkca\Desktop\{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid()), ImageFormat.Png);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot take picture if the camera isn't capturing image!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```